# What is the etiquette on requesting an upvote?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, up-votes

What is the etiquette on asking for upvotes?  i.e. I answered a question, and the person who asked wrote a comment saying my answer was very useful.  I am also the only answer, on the question and yet I don't have a single upvote.

I understand it would be inappropriate to ask for my answer to be picked as the correct answer.  However, I think maybe this person (who is very new), doesn't understand the purpose of upvotes.

Is it appropriate to request an upvote via a comment?

Comment: To be honest it's; don't

Comment: If the person is very new (below 15 points) they **cannot** upvote.

Comment: Are you asking about [CP1515n printer prints images in color but text in greyscale](http://superuser.com/a/652180)? Then the OP has not got enough reputation to vote **at all**.

Comment: Thank you all, I had forgotten that new users cannot upvote.

Answer (score 10):

Voting and accepting answers is entirely at the discretion of the person voting/accepting. It is never acceptable to ask someone to upvote or accept your answer (unless they actively ask you how it's done, or how they can mark the question as solved. Explaining the concept of accepting answers in general is also acceptable if the OP edits in [solved] or similar to their question; that should of course be done under the question comments).

Additionally as has been pointed out in comments; new users (<15 rep) cannot vote at all so requesting they do so will only lead to confusion.

Comment: What if the OP simply posts a comment to the answer, like *'thanks, that works'*, without marking as accepted? Especially in the case of new users, I have found it useful to reply with something like *'If this has helped you out, you can mark the answer as accepted'*.

Comment: @Hannele such comments should be put on under the question and not the specific answer, unless it is made by someone who hasn't answered the question (and even then it is better under the question as a teaching mechanism).

Comment: @Hannele Yes that is a bit of an edge case, an implied accept without actually accepting, I'm unsure of my opinion on that. But I think I agree with psubsee2003

Comment: @Hannele also, [Servy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198903/what-is-the-etiquette-on-requesting-an-upvote#comment631057_198905), in a comment on the other answer, brings up a good point... if the user has accepted answers in the past, then they know the feature and you shouldn't ask at all.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'll generally look at how much rep the user has. Posting on the question instead is a good point, although it's questionable how much neutrality that really implies. Anyways, I just wanted to point out that it's not necessarily an all or nothing thing.

Comment: @Hannele rep doesn't mean they don't know how to accept answers.  If they are low rep, then you should look in their profile to see if they have a history of accepting.  It is an extra 30 seconds to check usually.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's inappropriate to ask to be marked as accepted. This is one of the major functions of the site and allows future visitors to see, at a glance what the correct answer is. Questions are open indefinitely, unless there's a reason for closure, so your answer may not be the only answer forever. Ask them to click the tick mark button, it awards the OP reputation as well as yourself, he'd be doing himself a favour.

Regarding upvotes, all votes are anonymous so it's not really built to serve the purpose that you're expecting. The OP can accept and vote, and any other visitors can just vote.

In the case of your questions, it's better to ask for acceptance because the user is low rep, i.e. they may not be 100% familiar with the mechanics of the site.

Comment: As is stated in the OP of this question, you shouldn't be harping on people to accept an answer of yours.  They can accept an answer if they want to, and leave none accepted if they don't want to accept one.

Comment: Not 'harping', that's a strong word. Maybe in the case the OP is referring to, the question's OP has very low rep, this could suggest that they're new to SE. Maybe reminding them/informing them that they *can* accept a useful answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: I would prefer to make them *aware* of the system, just in case.  Even if my answer is the first one early on, I'll state that it's okay to accept any answer found most helpful over time.  I would also not mention my own question at all (so as to not "urge" an accept for myself), but in general.

Comment: @danielhanly.com the issue I have with your position is there is a big difference between commenting "Accept My Answer" and teaching the users about the features of the site.  Personally, I don't think you should ever comment "Accept my answer".  By commenting on the question and explaining how accepting works is a little more acceptable in my opinion (but it would be better coming from someone who isn't participating in the post)

Comment: @psubsee2003 In cases like this, I always aim to help the future visitors, i.e. what would a new visitor see when they visit the page. I wouldn't say "Accept My Answer", but I would allow them the opportunity to choose an answer. Often with 'quick fire' questions there are several dupe answers so it's not appropriate to say "me, me!" but if the user is new, it does help to inform them. I was a new user once, and I remember being informed of my 'rights' and it helped me adapt to the site

Comment: @danielhanly.com like I said, explaining how accepting works under the question is good.  Saying "if my answer helped you then you can click the green checkmark" under your answer is not appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think I'd probably comment on the question rather than the answer, and only if the question appeared to go cold for some time and the user was new. I'd also probably exercise common sense and read it on a case by case basis, rather than aiming for a rep increase.

Comment: @danielhanly.com if that's what you meant, then I think we're on the same page, however, your answer doesn't really reflect this position - hence my original comment.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if the user has ever accepted any answers, ever, then clearly they know how to use the feature, and you shouldn't be posting such a comment.